# How to add onClickListener for the android BACK button?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to implement a functionality that closes the application entirely by prompting the user with a dialog box when pressing the back button for android. By back button i refer to the actual physical button android smartphones tend to have in the bottom left of the device. The activity the functionality will take place in, is the last activity active for the application, all other have been closed using finish(). Normally, if the user pressed the back button in this scenario it will close them out of the application but not terminate it. In the code below i use finishAndRemoveTask() to temrinate the activity. Without the dialog box this works fine. However, when trying to add the dialog box, and call finishAndRemoveTask when the positive button is pressed, the application displays the dialog box for 0.2 seconds then closes, but not terminates.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        displayClosingAlertBox();
    }

    private void displayClosingAlertBox()
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.star_on)
                .setTitle("Exiting the Application")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.i("ON STOP: ", "YES");
                        finishAndRemoveTask();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling `super.onBackPressed();` if you don't want the default behavior to happen?

Comment: Nope no reason at all, not sure how i've missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to trigger the default behavior for `onBackPressed()`, don't call `super.onBackPressed()`.

Answer (score 1):

This may what you need, just remove super.onBackPressed() in your onBackPressed()

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     //   super.onBackPressed(); Remove this line
        displayClosingAlertBox();
    }

    private void displayClosingAlertBox(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.star_on)
                .setTitle("Exiting the Application")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.i("ON STOP: ", "YES");
                        finishAndRemoveTask();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }
```

Furthermore, you can choose whether the app needs to show the dialog or not by check a flag like this in your onBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if(isShowDialog){
     displayClosingAlertBox();
  } else {
     super.onBackPressed()
  }
}
```